# How to handle a puzzle derailment

Tags: discussion

I have an open puzzle, ([Who killed the indiscriminate warden?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/59412/who-killed-the-indiscriminate-warden)), that has some cryptic clues within it, one of which led someone to create a user ([kippered-fish-2851743](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/44684/kippered-fish-2851743)) named after one of the clues.  In addition, the user posted their own cryptic notes within the Profile section of the user, which has lead at least one user to contemplate the kippered-fish profile as a solution.

I worry that this has caused other possible puzzlers to think that it is actually a part of the solution, when it is not.  I edited my question to mention that the user profile is not related to the profile, but I worry that people will think that that statement is a red herring, and continue to try to decipher the inaccurate clues on the profile.

How should I handle this?

Comment: Doesn't SE have a hard rule against individuals operating multiple accounts? Could possibly just report that account as a sock puppet and get it shut down.

Comment: I thought of that.  Not sure if it was a new user that just created it as an attempt (in which case, the profile should stay), or if it is genuinely a secondary account.

Comment: @Guest You're not allowed to do things on a secondary account that your primary can't do (such as upvoting yourself), but having two accounts is otherwise OK.

Comment: @Guest [What ffao said](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/57685/278659).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> I edited my question to mention that the user profile is not related to the profile

That's by far the best thing you can do. Anyone who's trying to solve the puzzle will now see your note there, ensuring they won't go barking up that wrong tree. Anyone who sees the user but not the puzzle ... you don't have to worry about anyway.

If you suspect something more nefarious - e.g. someone is deliberately trying to sabotage your puzzle - you can raise a moderator flag and ask them to investigate. It could be that this is (for example) a sockpuppet of another user known for trollery. Or it could be a harmless joke. It could even possibly be a new user who doesn't realise that answers should be posted in answers rather than profiles (though this might be a stretch). Either way, your note in the question should ensure nobody wastes too much time thinking that user is a clue.

Comment: You mean I wasn't mean to post all my answers using glitter glue across Dave's desk? Better to learn now than never at least...